# How can I remove the session cookie from the response in my Rails project in order to support Xero Webhooks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, xero-api

I am trying to implement a [Xero Webhook](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/webhooks/creating-webhooks) in my Ruby on Rails application. However, the Xero documentation says that the response should not contain any cookie. Hence, I am trying to find a way to remove all the cookies from the response, but I have no luck. There is always a cookie with name `_rails-devise_session` which is the cookie to support sessions.

How can I have this cookie removed (or not present in the first place) but only for the specific end-point that serves the Xero Webhook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

in my controller, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the inflexibility and poor documentation of the Xero web hook API I created a file outside the framework and used `.htaccess` to to direct the incoming traffic.

Invalidating a cookie does not work, nor does setting the value to `null`.  If an array key for a cookie exists **at all**, the web hook will not function.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*xerowebhook /webhooklanding.php [QSA,L,END]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I have yet to find a viable alternative where session cookies are in use.